# Overlapping transparent backgrounds

Tags: html, css

I've set two `div` elements, with semi transparent gradient background set to one of them , overlapping each other. One of them is the header with higher `z-index` and semi transparent gradient, and the other is the the navbar. Both div colors mix and both are showing on the header.

How do I make only the header to show? I have looked everywhere but I have no clue to what to do.

Here is the code:

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}
#header {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 80px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 0 0 20% 30%;
  z-index: 1;
}
#nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(15% + .5px);
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

And a pic explaining where's the problem:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't this do exactly what you're telling it to do? You set transparency thus you can see the underlying elements. If you don't want that you need to work without transparency and use different shades of blue

Comment: Have some more options here, position your second background just below your header, use different shades of color for that section, separate. the divs completely and then apply background images

Comment: You can try to apply a gradient to your `#nav` so that it is `cornflowerblue` from bottom and `DodgerBlue` on the top, that way it achieves the same color as the background, which will make it seem transparent.

Comment: What im trying to acheive is that the header will catch the color of the container (DodgerBlue) with a gradient white tint to it, fading to the container (the header width is shorter than the container) . The navbar should get a solid color.  P.S. the header is curved just at that point due to border-radius. The desired effect is that the navbar should continue just underneath the curved header leaving no space between the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so i found the solution for this situation.
You need to create another `div` (I gave it `id="header_glow"` in the example to follow), make it the same dimensions as the header `div`, and set the `background: linear-gradient` only for this `div`. The header `div` should have solid background color. Give both `div`s a `z-index` that is equal to each other and bigger than the nav `z-index`.

CSS code:

```
#header {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  border-radius: 0 0 20% 20%;
  z-index: 1;
}
#header_glow {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 0 0 20% 20%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,
  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  z-index: 1;
}
#nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(15% + .5px);
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

[See Attached pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wak6D.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your css code is depicting absolute position for the nav and hence is overlapping the header.

You should remove the abs poss else there will be bleed because one is below the other - you cannot clip the element at intersection via css.

You could add an pseudo element :before on the navigation give at a height and width and abs pos it top left with a solid hex of the value or even white then an :after element over that of the opacity but that's a real hack way and suggest you change the markup/css to show the colour you want on the parent container of both the nav and the header.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so this is my solution: Just change top:0; to top:80px; of your nav style, it'll separate then

Comment: The header is curved at the desired position due to border-radius. Doing so would leave a gap between the elements on the curved area.

Comment: you can play with the border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px;